# "Cannot allocate memory" Using composer to install composer using fork from laravel git

Tags: php, nginx, git, php5

Whenever I try to install a new laravel project, I receive the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:990
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error may be occurring, I'm running the server on nginx.

If any other details may be required, list them as a comment and i'll happily edit + update the post, thank you.

Comment: Are you running this on a small, low-memory server of some sort? I've had issues with large Composer checkouts on AWS's t1.micro instances.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm running it on the $5 package by digitalocean.com, I've successfully installed projects with the exact same server a few months ago, so as far as I'm aware I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Depends on the size of the projects and how much RAM is in use for other things. The $5 servers are probably uncomfortably close to the limit. I'd do the `composer install` locally, then SCP the files up, as the initial Laravel checkout pulls a **lot** of stuff.

Comment: @ceejayoz hm okay, i'll give a try right now and i'll get back to you, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also, this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116261/php-composer-update-cannot-allocate-memory-error-using-laravel-4

Answer (score 1):

I am using scaleway.com server. I have RAM 2 GB. I also had this problem. I am using this command and this working for me

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G /usr/local/bin/composer install
```